# Convert curl to GOlang code

Tags: curl, go

I am a GO newbie. I am trying to convert a curl command to GOlang.

```
curl --cacert "pki/ca.crt" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer my_bearer_token" \
  --insecure \
  --max-time 5 --fail --output /dev/null --silent \
  "https://myserver/status"; do
```

This is what I have got:

```
mTLSConfig := &tls.Config {
    CipherSuites: []uint16 {
        tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
        tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
        tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
        tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
        tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
        tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
    },
    InsecureSkipVerify: true, // --insecure
}
mTLSConfig.PreferServerCipherSuites = true
mTLSConfig.MinVersion = tls.VersionTLS10
mTLSConfig.MaxVersion = tls.VersionTLS10
certs := x509.NewCertPool()
certs.AppendCertsFromPEM([]byte(caCert))
mTLSConfig.RootCAs = certs
tr := &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: mTLSConfig,
}

client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://myserver/status", nil)
req.Header.Set("Authorization", fmt.Sprintf("Bearer my_bearer_token"))
resp, err := client.Do(req)
glog.V(4).Info(resp, err)
if err != nil {
    return true
}
return false
```

Am I doing it right?

Comment: Why all the tls.Config stuff? None of that is in your curl command. Also, why is your curl command specifying a --cacert, then setting --insecure?

Comment: If the ca.crt isn't in your OS's trust store then you do need to set RootCAs. You don't need to set the rest of tlsconfig. The default tlsconfig is fine. You definitely don't need to set InsecureSkipVerify. Is something not working?